# Count number of selected columns without nan by rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where I want to count the number of selected columns, not all of them, that have nan value per row.

For example, the following dataset would need this logic.

[image]

I then need it to look like this:

[image]

This is counting the columns for each row that do not have nan. I have seen answers on how to count the total nan's but have not been able to find anything on how to do it with selected columns per row.

Answer (score 0):

Answer originally posted by Oxbowerce in comments:

> Subet set the dataframe to select only the A (or B or C) columns and count the number of NA's on the resulting dataframe: `df["Atotal"] = df[["A1", "A1"]].isna().sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
headers=['a1','a2','b1','b2','b3','c1','c2']
row1=[1,1,None,None,0.5,None,0]
row2=[1,None,1,None,1,1,None]
row3= [None,0,1,1,1,0,1]
row4=[0, None, None,0,0,1,1]

df = pd.DataFrame([row1,row2,row3,row4],columns=headers)
# add column with no of occurrence of Non None values in the column name starts with 'a'
df['a_total'] = df.filter(regex='^a').count(axis=1)
df['b_total'] = df.filter(regex='^b').count(axis=1)
df['c_total'] = df.filter(regex='^c').count(axis=1)

# OUTPUT
#     a1   a2   b1   b2   b3   c1   c2  a_total  b_total  c_total
# 0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  0.5  NaN  0.0        2        1        1
# 1  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN        1        2        1
# 2  NaN  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0        1        3        2
# 3  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0        1        2        2
```

If liked. upvote